# How to submit instagram app for POST requests?

Tags: ios, ios8, instagram, instagram-api

I want to follow user on Instagram. 
As described in Instagram documentation [Relationship Endpoints.](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/?hl=en)

I am requesting POST:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

but getting error : which in short says send app for approval.

When i go to approval [Request access to Instagram API endpoints.](https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116)

In **Who will be able to use your application?** it does not allow me to select **Anyone** & send for approval.

I am an individual developer so how i can send my app for approval?

Answer (score 0):

They make it clear in their Help Center, only applications that offer business services can have access to POST and DELETE

> The ability to POST and DELETE likes, follows and comments is
>   restricted to applications that offer business services and not
>   consumer facing apps

They even said:

> Please do not submit a request at this time.

[Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116)